# Pipenv: There are incompatible versions in the resolved dependencies

Tags: python, python-3.x, pipenv, pipfile, pipenv-install

I am using `$ pipenv install` to update the **Pipfile.lock**
, it just complains with this error:

```
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies...
Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
✔ Success! 
Locking [packages] dependencies...
Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
✘ Locking Failed! 
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/home/mostafa/.local/share/virtualenvs/carfix-5kWau1IT/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 741, in _main
[ResolutionFailure]:       resolve_packages(pre, clear, verbose, system, write, requirements_dir, packages, dev)
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/home/mostafa/.local/share/virtualenvs/carfix-5kWau1IT/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 702, in resolve_packages
[ResolutionFailure]:       results, resolver = resolve(
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/home/mostafa/.local/share/virtualenvs/carfix-5kWau1IT/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 684, in resolve
[ResolutionFailure]:       return resolve_deps(
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/home/mostafa/.local/share/virtualenvs/carfix-5kWau1IT/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 1397, in resolve_deps
[ResolutionFailure]:       results, hashes, markers_lookup, resolver, skipped = actually_resolve_deps(
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/home/mostafa/.local/share/virtualenvs/carfix-5kWau1IT/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 1110, in actually_resolve_deps
[ResolutionFailure]:       resolver.resolve()
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/home/mostafa/.local/share/virtualenvs/carfix-5kWau1IT/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 835, in resolve
[ResolutionFailure]:       raise ResolutionFailure(message=str(e))
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]: Warning: Your dependencies could not be resolved. You likely have a mismatch in your sub-dependencies.
  First try clearing your dependency cache with $ pipenv lock --clear, then try the original command again.
 Alternatively, you can use $ pipenv install --skip-lock to bypass this mechanism, then run $ pipenv graph to inspect the situation.
  Hint: try $ pipenv lock --pre if it is a pre-release dependency.
ERROR: Could not find a version that matches daphne<4,==2.4.*,>=3.0 (from -r /tmp/pipenvg7ot2kttrequirements/pipenv-ndlkbmk7-constraints.txt (line 20))
Tried: 0.8.1, 0.8.2, 0.9, 0.9.1, 0.9.2, 0.9.3, 0.10.0, 0.10.0, 0.10.1, 0.10.1, 0.10.2, 0.10.2, 0.10.3, 0.11.0, 0.11.0, 0.11.1, 0.11.1, 0.11.2, 0.11.2, 0.11.3, 0.11.3, 0.12.0, 0.12.0, 0.12.1, 0.12.1, 0.12.2, 0.12.2, 0.13.0, 0.13.0, 0.13.1, 0.13.1, 0.14.0, 0.14.0, 0.14.1, 0.14.1, 0.14.2, 0.14.2, 0.14.3, 0.14.3, 0.15.0, 0.15.0, 1.0.0, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.3, 1.1.0, 1.1.0, 1.2.0, 1.2.0, 1.3.0, 1.3.0, 1.4.0, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.2, 2.0.0, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.3, 2.0.4, 2.0.4, 2.1.0, 2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.1.2, 2.2.0, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.2.2, 2.2.3, 2.2.3, 2.2.4, 2.2.4, 2.2.5, 2.2.5, 2.3.0, 2.3.0, 2.4.0, 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.4.1, 2.5.0, 2.5.0, 3.0.0, 3.0.0, 3.0.1, 3.0.1, 3.0.2, 3.0.2
There are incompatible versions in the resolved dependencies:
  daphne==2.4.* (from -r /tmp/pipenvg7ot2kttrequirements/pipenv-ndlkbmk7-constraints.txt (line 20))
  daphne<4,>=3.0 (from channels==3.0.4->-r /tmp/pipenvg7ot2kttrequirements/pipenv-ndlkbmk7-constraints.txt (line 19))
```

I tried these commands but the problem is not yet resolved:

`pipenv lock --clear` and `pipenv lock --pre --clear`

`pip uninstall pipenv` then `pip install pipenv`

Comment: Try `--pre`, as recommended in error, it helped me. Probably `daphne` is a pre-repease version